# angular variable generating html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am trying to make a blog page with angularJS and on the message part i have a div like this.

```
<div class="post-content">
    {{jsonPost.message}}
</div>
```

and inside the variable jsonPost.message i got a string like this

```
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

but instead creating 2 html paragraphs, instead i see the `<p>` texts on the screen aswell like a text. Is there a way to make them html code ? and than target them via css.
Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: Have you tried using ngBindHtmlUnsafe?  Take a look at this,  I haven't used it yet so I am not posting it as an answer. http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using v1.2, you need to use `ng-bind-html`. To bypass sanitization use `$sce` service:

```
$scope.jsonPost.message = $sce.trustAsHtml("<p>paragraph 1</p>");
```

HTML:

```
<!-- bypasses sanitizaton -->
<div data-ng-bind-html="jsonPost.message"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`:

```
<div class="post-content" ng-bind-html-unsafe="jsonPost.message"></div>
```

Comment: Note: this will not work in Angular 1.2+  It has been replaced with Strict Contextual Escaping. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce