# Change specific words of string to bold

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a a single span element in my page.  I am concatenating words to a single variable in AngularJS and then referencing the variable to the span element in the page.

```
$scope.abc = "Downstream";
$scope.abc.concat('<b>','Upstream',</b>);
```

When the page is viewed, it displays `Downstream<b>Upstream</b>`

How to display the word Upstream alone in Bold?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

You need to include the ngBindHtml and $sanitize service

In your js file, it should be

```
angular.module('App', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('Ctr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.abc = "Downstream";
     $scope.abc2 = $scope.abc.concat('<b>','Upstream','</b>');
}]);
```

In your html file, it should be

```
<div ng-controller="Ctr">
    <p ng-bind-html="abc2"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems a duplicate to [angular variable generating html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771822/angular-variable-generating-html).

I don't know angular, but reading that post it's easy. Just do:

```
 $scope.abc = $scope.trustAsHtml($scope.abc);
```

HTML

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="abc "></div>
```

---

Also check your Angular version, for version 1.2 or lower you could use the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` binding.

```
<div class="post-content" ng-bind-html-unsafe="abc"></div>
```

This does not work anymore at Angular 1.2+ According to comment of `TheSharpieOne`:

"It has been replaced with Strict Contextual Escaping. See [docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)"

Comment: ns-sanitize also has to be included. Thanks for the answer!