# HTML break line using <br> tag in <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML, I am using

to show some text, like this:

```
 <p> {{item.bio}} </p>
```

And here is the sample of bio object:

```
 "bio": "A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br>E<br>F"
```

I was expecting that I'll get each and every alphabet in separate lines, but worst thing is when I run my HTML, showing me text as it is written with `<br>` tag.

Comment: Your [MCVE] is missing the JavaScript (so it isn't complete or verifiable). We can't tell what is replacing that template placeholder with the data. (There are several different template languages that use similar syntax out there, and they work in different ways)

Comment: Or handlebars? :) in which case you could use `{{{item.bio}}}`

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal yes I am working on Ionic project

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771822/angular-variable-generating-html

Comment: maybe this link will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754515/how-to-render-html-with-angular-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way. Use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) in your module's dependencies.

Your code would we like:

```
<p ng-bind-html="item.bio"></p>
```

For more details read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: most easiest and best solution :) I tapped as useful and will accept soon

Answer (score 1):

For inserting html in ionic V1 you should use `ng-bind-html` directive:

```
 <div ng-bind-html="item.bio"></div>
```

and for second version

```
<div [innerHTML]="item.bio"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

```
 angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
           .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
             $scope.snippet =
               '<p style="color:blue">an html\n' +
               '<em onmouseover="this.textContent=\'PWN3D!\'">click here</em>\n' +
               'snippet</p>';
             $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
               return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
             };
           }]);
```